# Trigger not saving historicals

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Version: SQL Server 2008 R2

This trigger checks primary key violations, if any moves the row to the history table; and then deletes the row; and then inserts the row that caused the violation.

But it is not doing its job.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ONINSERT]
   ON  [dbo].[TICKETS]
   Instead of INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(200)
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @ID = (SELECT TICKET_ID FROM inserted)

    INSERT TICKET_HISTORY
    SELECT * FROM TICKETS  
    WHERE 
    TICKET_ID = @ID ;
    print 'Inserting ' + @id

    DELETE FROM TICKETS
    WHERE TICKET_ID = @ID; 
    print 'Deleting' + @id

    INSERT TICKETS
    SELECT * FROM inserted; 
    print 'Inserting back' + @id
```

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it  will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Answer (score 0):

Triggers fire only once even if you have multiple inserts,so in your case I don't see that happening...You don't need to delete the row again since instead of insert generally means "instead of insert do some custom action"

```
  if exists
    (
    select 1 from inserted i
    join
    mytable t
    on t.id=i.id
    )
    begin
    --insert into tickets history
    insert into ticketshistory
    select i.* from inserted i
    join
    mytable t where t.id=i.id
---you can add custom logic to alert or simply ignore
    return

    end
    --this is needed since if there is no violation you have to insert rows
    insert into tickets
    select * from inserted
```